# Как отфильтровать все теги, кроме  img?

Tags: теги, php

В общем, проблема такая: можно ли, чтобы функция `htmlspecialchars()` фильтровала все теги, кроме `<img/>` или как это можно организовать другими функциями.

Заранее Спасибо!

Answer (score 5):

Как вариант:

```
$str = "<p><img src='bla-bla.jpg' border=2></p>"; // Строка для фильтрации
$str = htmlspecialchars($str, ENT_NOQUOTES);
$str = preg_replace('#&lt;img(.*)&gt;#Usi', '<img$1>', $str);
```

Я проверил - работает)
Объясняю:
С помощью функции htmlspecialchars мы заменяем у тегов символы "<" и ">" на "&lt;" и "&gt;" соответственно. Т.к. нам нужно сохранить все теги img, мы заменяем обратно на символы "<" и ">" у всех тегов img с помощью регулярного выражения, про них лучше почитайте статьи, очень важная штука в программировании.

Comment: обясните всё это если не сложно?

Answer (score 3):

```
strip_tags($text, '<img>');
```